# Validaciones condicionales rails diferenciando create de find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, condiciones, ruby, validación, activerecord

Tengo un problema, estoy trabajando con dos modelos uno Company y otro Partner, en el controlador de Partner tengo la creacion de una Company vía find_or_create_by y en el controlador de Company, puedo crear una company directamente con sus parámetros.

El problema está en que en el modelo de Company tengo algunas validaciones para generar el registro, pero necesito que al usar find_or_create_by desde partner pueda hacer el registro saltándose algunas de estas validaciones, tengo una idea mas o menos de como hacerlo con condicionales, pero aún no me queda claro.

```rb
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @company = Company.new(company_params)
        @company.save
    end
end
```

```rb
class PartnersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        company_new = Company.find_or_create_by(partner_params[:company])
        @partner = Partner.create(partner_params[:partner])
        @partner.partner_company = company_new
        @partner.save
    end
end
```

como lo puedo hacer para diferenciarlos y que al crear el registro de company nuevo desde mi controlador company se ejecuten algunas de las validaciones que necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No explicas cuales son las ideas que tienes de como hacerlo, pero así de primeras se me ocurren 2 formas. Una podría ser haciendo una sub clase de la principal que tuviese todas las validaciones:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class FullCompany < Company
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

aunque creo que esto podría llegar a ser más engorroso para mantener a medida que crezca el código. Lo otro es que tengas un atributo que condicione la ejecución de una u otra validación:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :lax_validation

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, unless: :lax_validation
end
```

> desde partner pueda hacer el registro saltándose algunas de estas
> validaciones

> desde mi controlador company se ejecuten algunas de las validaciones

Tampoco estás dejando claro desde cual controlador quieres ejecutar solo algunas validaciones, pero luego deberías hacer algo como:

```
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
    @company.lax_validation = true
```

o también te sirve:

```
  company_new = Company.find_or_create_by(
    partner_params[:company].merge(lax_validation: true)
  )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, están muy claras y mi idea principal era agregando la variable al controlador, hice algo similar pero con un bloque en el modelo with_options if: :skip_validate? do |company| entonces dentro de este, metí las validaciones dentro de este bloque. Saludos